# zsh: check if string is in array

Tags: arrays, zsh

E.g.

```
foo=(a b c)
```

Now, how can I do an easy check if `b` is in `$foo`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use reverse subscripting:

```
pax$ foo=(a b c)

pax$ if [[ ${foo[(r)b]} == b ]] ; then ; echo yes ; else ; echo no ; fi
yes

pax$ if [[ ${foo[(r)x]} == x ]] ; then ; echo yes ; else ; echo no ; fi
no
```

You'll find the datails under `man zshparam` under `Subscript Flags` (at least in `zsh 4.3.10` under `Ubuntu 10.10`).

---

Alternatively (thanks to [geekosaur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643977/geekosaur) for this), you can use:

```
pax$ if [[ ${foo[(i)b]} -le ${#foo} ]] ; then ; echo yes ; else ; echo no ; fi
```

You can see what you get out of those two expressions by simply doing:

```
pax$ echo ${foo[(i)a]} ${#foo}
1 3

pax$ echo ${foo[(i)b]} ${#foo}
2 3

pax$ echo ${foo[(i)c]} ${#foo}
3 3

pax$ echo ${foo[(i)d]} ${#foo}
4 3
```

Comment: The `(i)` modifier may be more useful, in the case where there are empty strings in the array:  it returns the index of the match, which can be compared against `${#foo}`.

Comment: Good point @geekosaur. Added that option to the answer as well.

Comment: Also: `if (( ${foo[(i)b]} <= ${#foo} ))`

Comment: Or: `if (( ${+foo[(r)b]} )) ; then ; echo yes ; else ; echo no ; fi`

Comment: @drumfire FYI that approach seems to fail when the array was created from the [`mapfile`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12652267/2954547).

Comment: You need to make clear the `(r)` subscript flag expects a pattern. `foo=( abc 'a(b)c' ); bar=$foo[2]; echo ${foo[(r)$bar]}` will print `abc` and **not** `a(b)c`. In cases where you do not want the input to the `(r)` subscript flag to be interpreted as a pattern (possibly more likely than not), and therefore don't want to be caught out by this, you also need the `(e)` subscript flag: `${foo[(re)$bar]}`.

Comment: how to do it without putting array into variable?

Comment: @minseong If you don’t need the array afterwords, you can use Bash syntax `[[ $var == (a|b|c) ]]`. I don’t think subscript syntax works with array literals.

Answer (score 23):

```
(( ${foo[(I)b]} )) \
  && echo "it's in" \
  || echo "it's somewhere else maybe"
```

Comment: This  is so concise and elegant - zsh arithmetic evaluation has return status 1 when evaluated expression is 0, or 1 otherwise. Very useful idiom +1M

Comment: use `(Ie)` if you need an exact match, because `(I)` is a pattern match.

Answer (score 6):

Reverse subscripts will always return something if a match is found and will return nothing if a match is not found. We can use this to simplify the answer even more.

```
$ foo=(a b c)

$ [[ -n "${foo[(r)b]}" ]] && echo 'b was found.' || echo 'b was not found.'
b was found.

$ [[ -n "${foo[(r)d]}" ]] && echo 'd was found.' || echo 'd was not found.'
d was not found.
```